# Add Comment button not working in FireFox 3.6.10?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Just started happening today for me. I click the "Add Comment" button below any given post and nothing happens. No box appears for me to type, nor do any notifications on closed questions. I'm definitely logged in, have tried logging in and out and I certainly have the required rep for it.

I'm using FireFox 3.6.10. IE 7 & 8 both work fine. Have not tested Safari/Opera/anything else.

Anybody else experiencing this?

Comment: Tested in 3.6.9 and it works fine... don't have 3.6.10 yet at work, so I can't test that.

Comment: I'm using FF3.6.10 as well, but I can't reproduce this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably clear your cache.

Comment: It's not having the issue at my home computer, so I will try when I get back to my work laptop on Monday.

Comment: Clearing the cache worked. Thanks Jeff.